# iOS - Show UIPopoverController with TableView from Navigation Toolbarbutton

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I would like to display a UIPopoverController in my iPad app when the user taps a button which is at the lower toolbar provided by my NavigationController. Is there a tutorial on how I can do this? All I found was ancient tutorials from 2010.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)ButtunClickMethod:(id)sender{
 //create the table view controller from nib
        self.tblLisView = [[[tableListVC alloc] 
                                        initWithNibName:@"tableListVC" 
                                        bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];

        //set popover content size
        tblLisView.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(170, 170);

        //create a popover controller
        self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                   initWithContentViewController:tblLisView] autorelease];


        //present the popover view non-modal with a
        //refrence to the button pressed within the current view
        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverButton.frame
                                                inView:self.view
                              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                                              animated:YES];
}
```